# background color of figures in tikz manual

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

The color background of figures in tikz manual is really good. Its some sort of beige or cream color. How can we apply this in our own figures. Secondly I want to have this as background color for my beamer slides. How to do that ?

Comment: The figure examples are typeset within an 'environment' named `codeexample` which both shows code and the output of it. See `/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pgf/macros>pgfmanual-en-macros.tex` for more information (on TeXLive, however)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per Christian Hupfer's comment, you can find the definitions in `/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pgf/macros/pg‌​fmanual-en-macros.te‌​x`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{graphicbackground}{rgb}{0.96,0.96,0.8}
\definecolor{codebackground}{rgb}{0.9,0.9,1}
\begin{document}

\colorbox{graphicbackground}{Ti\textit{k}Z graphic background}

\colorbox{codebackground}{Ti\textit{k}Z code background}

\end{document}
```

[image]

To set this color for the background of your beamer presentations, simply use

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\definecolor{graphicbackground}{rgb}{0.96,0.96,0.8}
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=graphicbackground}
```